# DDD - Queries to entities that are within an aggregate root

Tags: backend, domain-driven-design

I am making a practice application that allows me to learn about DDD.

The domain is simple. A recruiter creates a job offer where many applicants can apply to this offer.

Now, so far I have these classes:

Here I have identified the job offer as the aggregate and the application as an entity living within the aggregate.

The problem here is with this requirement I want to make: I need an applicant to be able to see all the applications I have made, and also to be able to see the details of each one.

Here I am starting to have a lot of doubts about how to do this.

First, DDD tells me that I can only have one DbSet per root aggregate, so that entities outside its aggregate cannot be accessed.

So I can't do this:
`_ctx.Postulations.Where(p => p.Candidate.Id == idParam)`
since I would not have the dbset of postulations.

Another thing that occurred to me is to create an auxiliary list, go through the job offers, get applications and save them in the auxiliary list and then return them, but I don't think it is the right thing to do.

How could I solve it here? I can't see it.

Then, if I want to get a post by id and then show it in details, I would think about having my own repository for post. But DDD says I can only have one repository per aggregate root.

I hope you can help me understand, I am very confused.
Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean "aggregate" by  "root aggregate"? What is "Postulations"? What is the "Post"? In your question, there wasn't any information about it, As you said, there are Job offers, Applications, and Applicants. The question is misleading. The most important concept of DDD is the UL. Don't use interchangeable words for the same concept.